# Location updates update only the marker but not the map. Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm receiving a stream of Positions , I than update a `_position`variable that is used both in `center:` to set the map position, and in the `Marker` I use to show user position.
The problem is that the marker gets updated, but not the map position.
The expected behaviour is that the Marker, stays steady on the centre of the screen while the map moves underneath it, but it happen the opposite. Can you see where I set things wrong?
many thanks for your time and help.

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String name;

  HomeScreen({
    Key key,
    @required this.name,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  Geolocator _geolocator;
  Position _position;

  FlutterMap _flutterMap;
  MapOptions _mapOptions;
  MapController _controller;
  void checkPermission() {
    _geolocator.checkGeolocationPermissionStatus().then((status) {
      print('status: $status');
    });
    _geolocator
        .checkGeolocationPermissionStatus(
            locationPermission: GeolocationPermission.locationAlways)
        .then((status) {
      print('always status: $status');
    });
    _geolocator.checkGeolocationPermissionStatus(
        locationPermission: GeolocationPermission.locationWhenInUse)
      ..then((status) {
        print('whenInUse status: $status');
      });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _geolocator = Geolocator();
    checkPermission();
    updateLocation();
  }

  void setMap() {
    _controller = MapController();
    _mapOptions = MapOptions(
      center: LatLng(_position.latitude, _position.longitude),
      minZoom: 16.0,
      maxZoom: 19.0,
    );
    _flutterMap = FlutterMap(
      options: _mapOptions,
      mapController: _controller,
      layers: [
//        PolygonLayer(polygonOpts, map, stream)
//                    PolygonLayerOptions(
//                      polygons:
//                    ),
        TileLayerOptions(
//        urlTemplate:'https://api.openrouteservice.org/mapsurfer/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?api_key=5b3ce3597851110001cf62484c4b65d85bc844eca3a2c6b9f300ddf4',
            urlTemplate: 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
            keepBuffer: 20),
        new MarkerLayerOptions(
          markers: [
            Marker(
              point: LatLng(_position.latitude, _position.longitude),
              height: 200,
              width: 200,
              builder: (context) => IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.location_on),
                color: Colors.red,
                iconSize: 60,
                onPressed: () {
                  print('icon tapped');
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  void startTracking() {
    LocationOptions locationOptions =
        LocationOptions(accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high, distanceFilter: 0);

    StreamSubscription positionStream = _geolocator
        .getPositionStream(locationOptions)
        .listen((Position position) {
      setState(() {
        _position = position;
        if (_position != null) {
//          _controller.move(LatLng(_position.latitude, _position.longitude), 16);
          setMap();
        }
      });
      print(
          _position.latitude.toString() + ',' + _position.longitude.toString());
    });
  }

  void updateLocation() async {
    try {
      Position newPosition = await _geolocator
          .getCurrentPosition(
            desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.bestForNavigation,
          )
          .timeout(new Duration(seconds: 5));
      print(
          'updateLocation(): ${newPosition.latitude.toString() + ',' + newPosition.longitude.toString()}');

      setState(() {
        _position = newPosition;
        setMap();
      });
    } catch (error) {
      print('Error updating location: ${error.toString()}');
    }
  }

  void postRequest() async {
    print('postRequest called');

    // working properly
//    final request =
//    'http://router.project-osrm.org/trip/v1/driving/44.5018645003438,11.340018709036542;44.501342559233315,11.336182647230146?exclude=motorway';
//    final request = 'http://router.project-osrm.org/trip/v1/driving/44.5018645003438,11.340018709036542;44.501342559233315,11.33618264723014?source=first&destination=last&roundtrip=false&exclude=motorway&generate_hints=false&geometries=geojson&overview=full';
//    final request =
//        'http://www.yournavigation.org/api/1.0/gosmore.php?format=geojson&v=bicycle&fast=0&layer=mapnik&flat=44.5018645003438&flon=11.340018709036542&tlat=44.501342559233315&tlon=11.336182647230146&geometry=1&instructions=1&lang=it';

    // GOOOD
    final request =
        'http://www.yournavigation.org/api/1.0/gosmore.php?format=geojson&v=bicycle&fast=0&layer=mapnik&flat=44.5018645003438&flon=11.340018709036542&tlat=44.502138&tlon=11.340402&geometry=1&instructions=1&lang=it';

    // only driving
//    final request =
//        'http://www.yournavigation.org/api/1.0/gosmore.php?format=geojson&flat=52.215676&flon=5.963946&tlat=52.2573&tlon=6.1799&v=motorcar&fast=1&layer=mapnik';

//    final request =
//        'https://routing.openstreetmap.de/routed-foot/route/v1/driving/13.7807085453224,51.0536161;13.7835429,51.0515885?overview=false&geometries=polyline&steps=true';

    // Await the http get response, then decode the json-formatted response.
    var response = await get(request);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
      print('${jsonResponse.runtimeType} : $jsonResponse');
      List<dynamic> coordinates = jsonResponse['coordinates'];
      print('coordinates are : $coordinates');
      print('coordinates are: ${coordinates.length}');
      Map<String, dynamic> properties = jsonResponse['properties'];
//      print('properties are $properties');
      String distance = properties['distance'];
      print('Route is $distance Km long.');
      String instructions = properties['description'];
      print('instructions are $instructions');

      List<LatLng> suggestedRoute = [];
      for (int i = 0; i < (coordinates.length); i++) {
        dynamic coordinate = coordinates[i];
        LatLng position = LatLng(coordinate[1], coordinate[0]);
        suggestedRoute.add(position);
        print('position is $position');
        print(i);
      }
      print('suggestedRoute is $suggestedRoute');
    } else {
      print('Request failed with status: ${response.statusCode}.');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        title: Text(
          'Home',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.orangeAccent, fontSize: 40),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.exit_to_app,
              color: Colors.orange,
              size: 35,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              BlocProvider.of<AuthenticationBloc>(context).add(
                LoggedOut(),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
        minimum: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 670,
                width: 370,
                child: _flutterMap,

              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                onPressed: () {
                  startTracking();
//                  setState(() {
////                    updateLocation();
//                  });
//
                },
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'alert',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @pskink I'm just starting in Flutter and I still have to grasp the state concept I guess. When I set `_position` to the new coordinates in set state shouldn't update the state of everything using that variable, hence both the marker and the map center ?

Answer (score 1):

There is `GoogleMapController` with [moveCamera](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter/latest/google_maps_flutter/GoogleMapController/moveCamera.html) / [animateCamera](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter/latest/google_maps_flutter/GoogleMapController/animateCamera.html) methods. They accept `CameraUpdate` parameter with [CameraPosition](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter/latest/google_maps_flutter/CameraPosition/CameraPosition.html) as new target.

```dart
class LocationLabPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LocationLabPageState createState() => _LocationLabPageState();
}

class _LocationLabPageState extends State<LocationLabPage> {
  GoogleMapController _mapController;
  StreamSubscription _streamSubscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _streamSubscription = LocationService().locationStream.listen((event) {
      _mapController.moveCamera(CameraUpdate.newLatLng(LatLng(event.latitude, event.longitude)));
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _streamSubscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: GoogleMap(
        myLocationEnabled: true,
        myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(target: LatLng(37.7, -122.2), zoom: 9.0),
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _mapController = controller;
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer.,  I'm not using Google Maps but flutter_map package that also have the `move`. I'm just starting in Flutter and I still have to grasp the state concept I guess. When I set `_position` to the new coordinates in set state shouldn't update the state of everything using that variable, hence both the marker and the map `center` ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. 
`_controller` is initialised inside `setMap()` instead that inside `initState()`, so when I call `_controller.move(LatLng(_position.latitude, _position.longitude), 16);` inside `startTracking()` it thrown the error not having a connection to the map..and didn't move the map. 
Having it initialised inside `initState()` works as expected.
Many thanks